# How do you control the size and position of new controls when customising CFileDialog?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, customization, cfiledialog

I'm customising a CFileDialog "Save As" dialog, using the built in tools. I'm simply adding a new text label (**AddText** or **StartVisualGroup**) and a new combo box (**AddComboBox**). It all works fine, but I don't like the positioning and sizing of the new controls.

In every article I can find on the subject, new labels and combo boxes are shown to be aligned / sized as per the existing ones (i.e., the text aligns / sizes with "Save as type:", the new combo aligns / sizes with the save as type combo). I only seem to be able to get my controls to align under the save as type combo and have a small size.

I can't find any info on how to adjust the size or position of these controls.

Comment: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Did you try moving/sizing your control(s) by simply calling `MoveWindow()`? Of course you need to get the position and size of the other controls in the dialog. Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/open-and-save-as-dialog-boxes , especially the paragraphs about templates and control identifiers.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou Your link is for old-style Open/Save dialog templates. That's stated in the first paragraph of the link which you have posted.